# XNA Framework HiDef profile requires TextureFilter to be Point when using texture format Vector4

Tags: xna

Beginner question. Synopsis: my water effects does something that causes the drawing of my sky sphere to throw an exeption when run in full screen. The exception is:

> XNA Framework HiDef profile requires TextureFilter to be Point when
>   using texture format Vector4.

This happens both when I start in full screen directly or switch to full screen from windowed. It does NOT happen, however, if I comment out the drawing of my water.

So, what in my water effect can possibly cause the drawing of my sky sphere to choke???

Comment: Does your shader change the render states in any way?

Comment: It might be helpful if you could show some code, especially around the area where you hit that error.

Comment: Are you using BasicEffect or a custom shader?

Comment: With "water effect" I ment a custom shader. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `SamplerState[0]` to `SamplerState.PointClamp` before your `DrawIndexedPrimitive` call.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem. I was confronted with the same problem:
I used  a SurfaceFormat.Single-Texture to make some displacement in my HeightmapShader and everything works until I change the resolution (switched to Full-screen or back). During this switch my SkyboxDrawer complains about exact the same thing. But my Skybox-texture was in SurfaceFormat.Color, so the exception doesn't make sense at all.

So I start googling and found out, that Sharwn Hargreaves (a programmer of XNA with a [great blog on XNA](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/) and other stuff) mentioned that there is a bug in XNA4.0 connected to the [correct sync of settings of the sampler states with their C# counterparts](https://web.archive.org/web/20170123224349/http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com:80/forums/p/61268/392105.aspx).

My sampler looks like the following, so I thought all that should be done, was done.

```
texture Texture;
sampler TextureSampler = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Texture>;
    MinFilter = POINT;
    MagFilter = POINT;
    MipFilter = POINT;   
    AddressU  = Wrap;
    AddressV  = Wrap;
};
```

But what really solved the problem was setting the VertexTextureSampler before drawing my **Heightmap**. This made the given exception in my SkyboxDrawer disappear.

```
GraphicsDevice.VertexSamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;
```

For completeness: My SkyboxDrawer uses the BasicShader whereas my HeightmapDrawer uses a custom HeightmapShader. So the only connection between them are the states in the grafics pipeline.

But there is a unsolved "problem". As far as I know a vertex textures sampler in XNA only can use floating point based formats like [SurfaceFormat.Single, SurfaceFormat.Vector2, SurfaceFormat.HalfSingle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb200104%28v=xnagamestudio.41%29) and so on. These formats require POINT sampling. So why the hell am I able to change the GraficsDevice.VertexTextureSampler[*] to something else?! Did I miss something?